# Unable to get the right json property dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have following JSON structure:

```
var pages = {
    "yearly": {
        "MXN": {
            "id" : "2c92c0f940f1b6e50140f4b7d9054a6e",

        },
        "NZD": {
            "id" : "2c92c0f940f1b6d40140f4b7e14d66b7",
        }
    },
    "monthly": {
        "MXN": {
            "id" : "2c92c0f940f1b6d40140f4b40ed85c57",         
        },
        "NZD": {
            "id" : "2c92c0f840f1c2cc0140f4b3b15d3956",          
        }
    }

}
```

i want to get the values of json inside yearly property dynamically for example i get the dynamic value MXN inside a variable `currency` now i am having problem in accessing its value i am trying to access it like this:

```
pages.yearly[currency].id
```

but i am unable to get to that `id` property gives me error of `TypeError: pages.monthly[currency] is undefined` what is wrong in my syntax that is causing type error??

Comment: There's no JSON in this question, this is a literal JS object.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in a fiddle or give us a more complete code ?

Comment: [Works here](http://jsfiddle.net/amq9Y/).

Comment: It looks like you are missing an entry in your `pages.monthly` object. Are you sure there is an entry for the currency you're looking up?

Comment: Just slapped it down in Chrome console and it works fine.  Agree with others, show us a fiddle or something.  My money is that something is wrong with the value in `currency`

Comment: Does currency have a string stored in it? Also, that is not a jQuery error but  Javascript error.

Comment: I think, you should post more code, exact code that produces the error.

Comment: I figured it out eventually after hardwork of looking each character.Actually i was having some problem with a long structure of Json and was missing a bracket.which wasn't highlighted because i am using notepad so once again thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The according to this error the variable `currency` needs to be defined. For example

```
var currency = "MXN";
```

Comment: Thanks mate your answer was able to give me the direction toward solving my prblem